# Is there an easy way to install opencv 3 on mac through anaconda?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda

Is there an easy way to install opencv 3 on mac through anaconda?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No there is no easy way to install it but here is a website that could help you a little bit. http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am searching for the tutorial for the installation through anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Python 2.7, you just copy the .pyd file from OpenCV installation folder. If you used Python 3, check these out:

[Install OpenCV 3.0 and Python 3.4+ on OSX](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/)

or

[Install OpenCV 3 for Python 3 on OSX](http://tsaith.github.io/install-opencv-3-for-python-3-on-osx.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am searching for the tutorial for the installation through anaconda.

Comment: @Condo_programmer I'm also using Anaconda, but in WIndows. You can try this also:

conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0